# Concating tiers for users with more than one tier, whilst using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping, concatenation

This query selects the following:

```
SELECT jobs.JobID, school.School_Name, 
       CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) AS 'Full_Name', 
       staff.Phone_Number, role.Role
  FROM jobs
 INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
 INNER JOIN staff ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
 INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
 ORDER BY staff.StaffID asc


JOB ID  FULL NAME   ROLE
------  ---------   ----------
1       BOB         PRINCIPLE
2       BOB         TEACHER
3       JACK        TEACHER
4       SARAH       ACCOUNTANT
5       SARAH       NURSE
```

However, I want the results to look like:

```
BOB     PRINCIPLE, TEACHER
JACK    TEACHER
SARAH   ACCOUNTANT, NURSE
```

I'm confused on how to concat this, as by adding a GROUP BY clause, it only selects the very first JobID?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Aggregate string concatenation functions are notoriously non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT Full_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Role) AS Role
  FROM
 (
  SELECT jobs.JobID, school.School_Name, CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) 
     AS Full_Name, staff.Phone_Number, role.Role
    FROM jobs
   INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
   INNER JOIN staff ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
   INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
   ORDER BY staff.StaffID asc
 ) q
GROUP BY Full_Name
```

Comment: you're welcome @GoGoAllen you can add those columns to the SELECT list also : `SELECT full_name, Phone_Number, School_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(job)...`. Btw, no need to add to the GROUP BY list.